# what is the prefer folder structure for laravel + angular

Tags: angular, laravel

what is the prefer folder structure for laravel + angular.

I want to setup my new project with laravel backend and angular as front end.

can any one suggest me, what is the good folder structure for my project which is  easily maintainable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am handling Angular 4 as front end and Laravel as backend API. I think the folder should not be merged (Angular within Laravel folder or reverse). It will make you confused. Angular works in a different way than the Laravel Blade.

I create 2 different folder, named ***frontend*** and ***backend***. The Angular Project will runs on port 4200 and I set up the environment so Angular will hit Laravel API which runs on port 8000.

[image]

Comment: - Yes, i think it would be better to keep them in separate folder and also they will be served on different domain.

Answer (score 1):

My project is in angular 1 and laravel 5.2. SO I have created one folder with project name and in that project folder I have created sub folder which contains angular code like it's controller, services,js files, views.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following structure:

1. Create a folder (your project name) in **htdocs**
2. Create 2 folders '**frontend**', '**backend**'. Your Angular code will  place in 'frontend' folder and your Laravel code will place in 'backend' folder
3. Create a proxy configuration in '**frontend**' to connect your Laravel code from your application. File name '**proxy.conf.json**'
   Content will be like this:

   {
   "/secure": {
   "target": "http://localhost/your project name/backend/",
   "secure": false
   },
   "/storage": {
   "target": "http://localhost/your project name/backend/",
   "secure": false
   },
   "/stream/*": {
   "target": "http://localhost/your project name/backend/",
   "secure": false,
   "ws": true
   }
   }
4. Add following code to your '**package.json**' in '**frontend**'

   "start": "**ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json**",
   [image]

5. Then you start running angular on your '**frontend**'. Ex: **npm start** OR **ng serve**